Simulator disappears in Xcode 15.3
This might be similar to this Xcode 9.0 simulators "disappeared"
I have periodically disappearing iOS simulator:

Rebooting/logging out and back in fixes it.
But the directories such as

/Applications/Xcode-15.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/DeviceTypes/iPad
Air (4th generation).simdevicetype/Contents/MacOS/iPad Air (4th
generation)

are in place as they should be cause the simulators were there ever since 15.3.1 was installed and used for the first time.
In fact there is a huge zoo of them
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad (10th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad (5th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad (6th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad (7th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad (8th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad (9th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Air (3rd generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Air (4th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Air (5th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Air 2.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (10.5-inch).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (11-inch) (1st generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) (16GB).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (1st generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) (16GB).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad Pro (9.7-inch).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad mini (5th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad mini (6th generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPad mini 4.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 11 Pro Max.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 11 Pro.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 11.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 12 Pro Max.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 12 Pro.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 12 mini.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 12.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 13 Pro Max.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 13 Pro.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 13 mini.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 13.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 14 Plus.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 14 Pro Max.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 14 Pro.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 14.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 15 Plus.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 15 Pro Max.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 15 Pro.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 15.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 6s Plus.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 6s.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:46 iPhone 7 Plus.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:46 iPhone 7.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 8 Plus.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone 8.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone SE (1st generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:46 iPhone SE (2nd generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone SE (3rd generation).simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone X.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone Xs Max.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone Xs.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPhone Xʀ.simdevicetype
drwxr-xr-x   3 agraph  staff    96 Feb  4 02:47 iPod touch (7th generation).simdevicetype

Also there are these (thank you @matt) inside /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 root  admin         224 Apr 12 18:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  admin         224 Aug  3  2023 ..
-rw-------  1 root  admin  7351124481 Jan  9 16:10 00470611-A65E-4C90-9320-B17E3DC07E08.dmg
-rw-------  1 root  admin  7229057541 Mar  6 15:38 400CE2B6-8AB0-44F8-939A-290B35DCBE8D.dmg
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  admin          64 Mar  6 15:38 Inbox
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin        2244 Apr 12 18:50 images.plist
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  admin          64 Mar  6 15:38 mnt

(and absolutely nothing inside /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/mnt/)
[What] is the[re a] way out of this predicament other than rebooting or relogin?

The presence or absence of the iOS 17.4 SDK has absolutely nothing to do with all that stuff inside Xcode. The SDK lives at /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images.

I have a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78418865/ios-sdk-17-4-periodically-disappears-in-xcode-15-3

I can confirm this behavior. I left my mac locked overnight and when I opened it in the morning Xcode had decided that the runtime was missing. Re-installing it failed with a message about trying to install a duplicate runtime. Re-starting Xcode fixed it for me without having to restart macOS.

The root cause is said to be XProtectPayload 132, as matt has pointed out.

Currently the only options seems to be

Restart Xcode.
If that does not help:
Reboot
Wait for Xcode newer than 15.3 and/or MacOS combo that fixes that
In the meantime if you have a puny 1/4 Tb drive


rm -rf ~/Library/Developer

(obviously the best timing for that before you are about to install a new version of Xcode to remove lots of old and presumably unused trash). Beware of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/474882/restore-simulators?noredirect=1#comment710223_474882 sideeffects though.

It worked. So weird.
