iOS SDK 17.4 periodically disappears in XCode 15.3
When I am trying to build a project in XCode I periodically get the following message:

when I click on "Download & Install" button it starts to download the simulator:

then after rebooting the machine I am able install SDK and build the project:


,but within some time this repeats again.
Similar question: Simulator disappears in Xcode 15.3

The same thing started to happen to us yesterday for Xcode 15.2 + iOS SDK 17.2. SDK disappears overnight

I am using Xcode 15.3 + iPhone 13 Pro Max iOS 17.4.1 and Xcode is not recognizing the device. Anybody with the same problem?
